# Picasso and PhotoView Library loads image into ImageView weird

Tags: android, image, picasso

I'm loading images into an ImageView with the Picasso library and then using the PhotoView Library to add zoom and panning etc.. to the ImageView.

But when picasso has loaded the image for the first time it displays the images like this:

[image]

But as soon I touch the image it places correctly

[image]

But if I close my app it suddenly doesn't show the image anymore and wont.

My MainActivity: 
http://pastebin.com/5H4zAgH

The libraries i'm using:

- http://square.github.io/picasso/
- https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem with the misplaced image when using Picasso and Photoview together.

To solve it, what I do is to use a callback when loading the image with Picasso using `into(view, callback)` instead of just `into(view)`. Once the image is loaded successfully I instantiate the PhotoViewAttacher object or call the method `update()`.

Here you have an example of code:

```
Callback imageLoadedCallback = new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        if(mAttacher!=null){
            mAttacher.update();
        }else{
            mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(mImageUrl)
.into(mImageView,imageLoadedCallback);
```

I hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: It seems to work better if I recreate the attacher each time rather than updating it.

Comment: what if i want to use viewpager ?

Answer (score 19):

I also had the same problem. I solved it by using `PhotoView` instead of `ImageView` and removed the `PhotoViewAttacher` from my code.

In layout file (if you use layout):

```
<uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/your_photo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ... />
```

And in your code:

```
PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.your_photo_view);
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(file)
        ...
        .into(photoView);
```

Now everything must be correct (at least for me it is!);

Comment: Thanks! Much cleaner than the callback solution!

Comment: which is the latest version for this ?