# Add Zoom in/out to ListView of Images?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, zooming

I have a fragment which contains a `ListView` and multiple images (7-10) are displaced each time fragment is launched.

I tried using different libraries for the zooming purpose but the `ListView` won't show up as then I will have to replace `ImageView` with library's defined `ImageView`

How can I add zoom in/out for those images?

EDIT: I want to add zoom in/out to the `ListView` that contain different number of images on each load, as my question states.

EDIT 2: This is `getview` method of my `Custom Adapter`. How do I attach [PhotoViewAttacher](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) in it?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View iv = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (iv == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        iv = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.image = (ImageView) iv.findViewById(R.id.imagview);
        iv.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) iv.getTag();
    }

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load((Integer) data.get(position))
            .resize(999, 720)
            .onlyScaleDown()
            .centerInside()
            .into(holder.image);

    return iv;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement zoom effect for image view in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399296/how-to-implement-zoom-effect-for-image-view-in-android)

Comment: @Rami I have written that my Images are in `ListView` and if if i use a lib ( as described in the answer to that question) for zooming it wont load the `ListView`, the libs i cam across are for single `ImageViews`.

Comment: can you add the code with the zoom method you implemented so we can try and figure out whats wrong?

Comment: @Anders Sure they are for single ImageView, you can use them in your getView() method of the adapter and apply the animation to your list item ImageView.

Comment: I tried one `ImageViewTouch` through my custom Adapter but my list wont show after adding it as i would have to use that lib's own imageview. so i thought it wont work that way, lemme try again with lib that is described in that question and then i will update my question okay

Comment: @Rami where i can find the jar file of [this library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/tree/master/library/src/main)? thanks for ur time

Comment: @Anders I don't think there is a .jar file, you need to integrate it with Gradle.

Comment: Second Answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749374/picasso-and-photoview-library-loads-image-into-imageview-weird) question worked perfect for me

Comment: @Rami I am using PhotoView with Picasso and some images appears smaller on listview? and first time some images are not loaded when i scroll, when i scroll back upward they start appearing?

Comment: 1) They appears smaller, maybe because they have a smaller size. Try to open the image  url in browser and check that. -- 2) Because the lib download images in AsyncTasks (asynchronous).

Comment: Actually am loading them from resources, with picasso alone they appear fine but when i use photoview then sometime there is gap between images and also some of the images are small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I made it work

After importing [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

In layout file (if you use layout):

```
<uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/your_photo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ... />
```

And in adapter

```
PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.your_photo_view);

Picasso.with(context)
    .load(file)
    ...
    .into(photoView);
```

Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: +1 for good qtn..-1 for bad answer.
Please post answer from that link..that link may be unavailable in future.

Comment: undo my down vote.where is uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView library link?

Comment: one upvote only allowed for me:).. already upvoted..thanks for good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking simple `ImageView` in `BaseAdapter`'s `getView` list item add 
[TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)